# Why does this kind of MDX Query always changed?

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I'm currently dealing with FoodMart DB in Mondrian.
Whenever I'm executing query which has this element:

```
...[Time].[Quarter].[Q1]...
...[Time].[Quarter].[Q2]...
...
```

After parsing the query, Mondrian always changes that query into this form:

```
...[Time].[1997].[Q1]...
...[Time].[1997].[Q2]...
...
```

Generally, both forms yield the same result. The problem is I have to keep the level from that query ([Quarter]) in order to achieve all its member later. What I mean is that I need to execute this kind of query:

```
...[Time].[Quarter].Members...
```

which apparently its result can not be achieved from this form:

```
...[Time].[1997].Members...
```

Does anyone know how to set Mondrian to keep my original query form? Or are there any way to get the level name ([Quarter]) from the given level ([1997]) ?

Thanks a lot!